# ¿Como agregar 7 columna en Sql?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo la siguiente consulta en la cual me arroja el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero agregarle una columna por cada fila, Muchas Gracias.

```
SELECT COUNT (ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE) as "" 
    FROM SOL_SOLICITUD_TPO_TRAMT_MODL WHERE ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT (ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE) 
    FROM SOL_SOLICITUD_TPO_TRAMT_MODL WHERE ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT (ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE) 
    FROM SOL_SOLICITUD_TPO_TRAMT_MODL WHERE ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE = 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT (ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE) 
    FROM SOL_SOLICITUD_TPO_TRAMT_MODL WHERE ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE = 4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT (ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE) 
    FROM SOL_SOLICITUD_TPO_TRAMT_MODL WHERE ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE = 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT (ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE) 
    FROM SOL_SOLICITUD_TPO_TRAMT_MODL WHERE ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE = 6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT (ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE) 
    FROM SOL_SOLICITUD_TPO_TRAMT_MODL WHERE ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE = 7;
```

Comment: No se que pretendas cfon esta query, pero podes meter todo eso en una subconsulta y pivotearla con otra tabla o podes agregar una columna a cada select. O tal vez preferis hacer un group by ?

Answer (score 0):

No ha puesto mucho esfuerzo en su pregunta. Leyendo su código SQL supongo lo que intente es agregar los tipos de trámite y la cantidad de cada tipo de trámite.

En SQL se puede usar una función de agregación (`count`) haciendo un `group by` para la/s columna/s non agregada/s.
He añadido un `order by` para ordernar por por dicha columna tipo de trámite.

```
select
  ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE,
  COUNT(ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE)
from SOL_SOLICITUD_TPO_TRAMT_MODL 
group by ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE 
order by ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar pivot, aquí te comparto la documentación para que te des una idea 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/sql/caracteristicas-database11g-2108415-esa.html. La consulta la podrías similar así:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select
    ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE,
    COUNT(ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE) AS ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE
    FROM SOL_SOLICITUD_TPO_TRAMT_MODL 
    GROUP BY ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE 
)TBL1
 PIVOT(
     COUNT(ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE)
     FOR ID_MODALIDAD_TIPO_TRAMITE IN ([a1], [2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])
 ) AS PivotTable
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.